# Escaping angle brackets in HTML email body

Tags: c#, escaping, html-email

My software sends html emails. The body contains angle brackets. To avoid recognizing them as html tags, I replace them with `&lt;` and `&gt;`

If I use this approach in an html document, it works well in a browser, and looks like normal angle brackets. But in an email (Outlook) it looks like "& lt;" and "& gt;". What is the right way of escaping angle brackets that would work with email messages?

Comment: No space, I placed it there only to avoid showing it as an angle bracket.

Comment: Add an [mre]. Too many questions now.

Comment: @Henk Holterman This is easy. In Outlook, just send to yourself an email with a text like "This is my test & lt;SOME TEXT HERE& gt;" and see the result. Just remove the spaces after &.

Comment: @DavidShochet That should work. It does for me. Therefore, I think it necessary to put the full code of what the final HTML that you're sending is--which is maybe what Henk was getting at. In this case, more context is necessary.

Comment: @Nathan If this works for you and not for me, just using Outlook without any code of my own, I am not sure what context I could provide... Maybe some Outlook settings, but I don't know which ones...

Comment: @DavidShochet It sounds like you are writing the email in Outlook itself. In that case, the characters are already escaped, and you do not need to replace angle brackets with `&lt;` and `&gt;`. Just copy the HTML as-is and send. Is that what you're doing?